# Are questions about whether certain types of hardware exist on-topic on Super User?

Tags: discussion

Another SuperUser user voted to have [my question](https://superuser.com/questions/1262059/are-there-any-large-4k-tvs-on-the-market-which-have-displayport-ports) closed as off-topic due to asking for recommendations. I asked whether 4K TVs with DisplayPort exist. That's not directly asking for recommendations, although providing examples of said items is ideal.

Assuming this does qualify as a recommendation question: [A question on the Meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/where-do-i-ask-hardware-related-questions) mentions hardware questions and that recommendations aren't allowed. Denying recommendations on StackExchange seems like a strange policy since there's a [SE site dedicated just to software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) and a similar one for [hardware recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) (beta).

Comment: Asking for list of things is off-topic on SU. Smart TVs are off-topic. Try [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).  but please first read [What is required for a question to be 'high quality'?"](http://hardwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-be-high-quality).

Comment: That TVs *can* be used with computers makes them only tangentially related to computers.  They are not *specifically* computer hardware in my book.  Whether they get DisplayPort is up to the manufacturers.

Comment: One of the reasons why product recommendation questions are off-topic is because the value of the information has a limited timeframe.  Asking whether something exists has that problem.  Today it might not, tomorrow it might.  It wouldn't have that issue if you ask a technical question, like "Is there a technical issue that precludes making ABC hardware that does X?" assuming the hardware is on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My take (as a user, not as a moderator) is that questions relating to hardware devices and how they connect to a computer would be on topic. Asking if a certain part exists feels very borderline.

Reasons to say it is off topic would include the fact that MANY questions asking this are poorly written, and are not received well by the community. Those that do ask good questions with the details we need to form a proper answer will usually involve turning it into a hardware recommendation (which is off topic).

My reason to say it is on topic is if it is being used strictly from a computer. In this case, it *may* also come down to an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and would need to be edited anyways.

In your particular case, with the 4K TVs with DisplayPort input, I'd probably re-write it to ask about what to look for to get 4K resolution through a DisplayPort cable, or something similar. If that happens to show off products that can do it, then the answers are hopefully helpful enough for the next person to understand that yes, something exists, or no, something does not exist.

Comment: I don't think my question qualifies as an XY problem. I am not looking for just any way to get a 4K signal to a TV or to a non-large DisplayPort display, and I am not interested in using a converter. I am considering having my question migrated to Hardware Recs SE.

Comment: @AaronFranke Yours isn't, but Meta is also about the general question population as well, not just yours.

Comment: There's also the problem of these questions becoming irrelevant *very* quickly, which raises the background noise level for others searching the site for answers.